# Does long-range Wi-Fi work well when traveling at high speeds?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wireless-bridge

We plan to have three RVs traveling together for several weeks and we would like to be able to work together during this time.

We considered using cellular (i.e. 3G) and web-based services, but much of the highway here has no coverage.  So I'm considering creating a LAN on-the-road using long-range Wi-Fi equipment--either directional AP/bridges [like these](http://www.engeniustech.com/business-networking/outdoor-access-points-client-bridges/9339-enh202-) or a directional antenna.

I've never heard of anyone doing this before.  I know Wi-Fi seems to work fine when using the mobile hotspot feature in my car, but that's only a meter or two away.  So the question is, does a 1 km Wi-Fi connection work just as well when stationary as when traveling 30 m/s?

Answer (score 1):

Radio waves travel *very* fast.  Since they are part of the electromagnetic spectrum, they travel at the speed of light (300,000 km per second) in space.  Here on Earth, they travel slower due to the fact that when passing through an object (air, walls, small animals, large rocks, etc), they are slowed according to that object's permeability and permittivity.

Police radios, CB radios, cell phones, etc, all use radio waves to communicate, all while on the move in cars.  So you *should* not have any issues.  Obviously, physical obstacles and interference can reduce effectiveness.  Directional antennas might also be in an issue if they are not aligned properly.

Comment: Right, it's just UHF.  I was more worried about things like signal processing getting messed up.  I will definitely be avoiding any of the new spatial filtering technology.

Comment: WiFi runs over TCP/IP, so assuming the signal isnt terrible, you might have packet loss, but still be functional.

Comment: There will be issues. The Doppler Effect should not be underestimated. The higher the frequency, the larger the shift. 30 m/s (delta!) will lead to a worst-case of ±240 Hz—meaning no reception at all.